# How to set listener for file field - when user selects file, take action

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have file upload field. When user selects file, a new field is added right underneath, allowing user to select another file, etc.

```
$("#photos").change(function(){
    var countEmpty = 0;
    $("#photos input").each(function(index) {
        if ( $(this).val() == '' )
            countEmpty++;
    });
    if (countEmpty == 0)
        addNewPhoto();
});
```

That's the code right now. It listens actually to a change in the div that contains the input fields. When it gets selected, clicked, or whatever, the script checks for empty fields. If no empty fields, it adds a new one.

But this has problem in IE8. In Firefox/Chrome, when user select file, new field appears right away. But in IE, user has to click whitespace, or scroll, or something - before the next field appear.

Any suggestions how to fix for IE?

Thanks.

PS: I have seen uploadifier but wouldn't be able to implement it for my project at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is to do with IEs implementation of `onChange`. In IE the input element must loose focus, if the value of that input has changed the `onChange` will then be fired. (btw look at the HTML 4 definition of `onChange`, IE actualy does it right where as Firefox... do it wrong http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#adef-onchange)

I would suggest changing your event from `onChange` to a different event e.g. `onClick`.